# put date string into JSON object in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format

Tags: android, json

I need to put `{"TargetDate":"2/22/2016"}` in json but by default adding '\' character with '/' this like `{"TargetDate":"2\/22\/2016"}`.

I need to set date into `mm/dd/yyyy` format in `JSON`.

Comment: use string `replace`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace it by,

```
String targetDate = "2\22\2016";
String correctFormatDate = targetDate.replace("/", "\");
```